# Prove that if A is countable, then so is $cl_f(A)$.

Tags: set-theory

Let B be a set and $f:B^m \rightarrow B$. By definition, given a subset $A \subseteq B$, the closure of $A$ under $f$, denoted by $cl_{f}(A)$, is the smallest subset of $B$ which contains $A$ and is closed under $f$.

Prove that if A is countable, then so is $cl_f(A)$.

My question is, how do I define a function such that $cl_f(A) \mapsto A$.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to find such a function (I presume you want an injective one, since otherwise you don't get anything out of it). To see this, suppose $B=\mathbb{N}, m=1, f(x)=x+1,$ and $A=\{1\}$. Then $cl_f(A)=\mathbb{N}$, while $A$ itself of course is finite.

The argument that $cl_f(A)$ is countable if $A$ is will have to be more abstract. For simplicity, let's assume that $m=1$ - so $f:B\rightarrow B$. The closure $cl_f(A)$ can be broken up as follows:

- Let $A_0=A$.
- Having defined $A_n$, let $A_{n+1}=\{f(x): x\in A_n\}$.

We can now show (**exercise**) that $cl_f(A)=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} A_n$.

Now we use the important fact (**exercise**) that the union of countably many countable sets is countable. Together with the previous point, this tells us that it will be enough to show that each $A_n$ is countable.

So now the question is, how do we do *that*? The answer is induction: we want to prove, by induction on $n$, that $A_n$ is countable. For $n=0$ it's true by assumption (remember $A_0=A$).

Now suppose $A_n$ is countable; how do we know that $A_{n+1}$ is also countable? This is going to follow from the following more general fact (**exercise**): that if $X\subseteq B$ is countable, then $\{f(x): x\in X\}$ is countable. This is sort of the "one-step" version of the thing you're actually trying to prove; note that in general $\{f(x): x\in X\}$ is *much smaller* than $cl_f(X)$.

So that's how the proof will go:

- Show how we can decompose $cl_f(A)$ into countably many pieces.
- Prove that the "one-step closure" of a countable set is countable.
- Use that to show by induction that each piece of $cl_f(A)$ is countable, if $A$ itself is.
- Finish using the fact that a countable union of countable sets is countable.

---

Note that the exercises above are really of two distinct flavors. The second and third are directly about the manipulation of countable sets, while the first is really about *finite* sets (or rather, finite sequences).

Note also that the first and third exercises become more complicated when we go from $m=1$ to the general case. In particular, the general version of the third exercise is an application of a stronger version of the second exercise: that if I take the finite Cartesian product of countable sets, the result is still countable. *(It's a good exercise to show that the word "finite" is necessary there: show that the Cartesian product of $\mathbb{N}$-many copies of $\{1, 2\}$ is uncountable.)*